# How to create a node revision view with a "Node" row style?

Tags: 7, views

Is it possible to create a node revision view with a "Node" row style?

This does not seem to be an option in the Views interface. "Fields" is the only options presented for this type of view. Is there a reason why this is not technically possible or is it just not currently implemented?

Comment: The 3.x branch is valid for both 6.x and 7.x (6.x-3.x was created before 7.x-3.x), so the tag is valid assuming the markdorison is referring to the 3.x version.

Comment: Yes, the tags are correct, as is @hefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer to my original question is no, it is not possible (please update if Views changes to allow this).

To accomplish what I needed, I ended up creating a custom module instead of using Views. I lifted the query that Views had generated as this was essentially what I needed. After returning the nid's of the nodes in question, I have drupal theme the nodes:

```
theme('node', $node, $teaser, $page);
```

Add each themed node to an array, `$items`, and then theme that array into an unordered list:

```
$rendered_list = theme('item_list', $items, NULL, 'ul', array());
```

I then set the block's content to that returned list.

```
$block['content'] = $rendered_list;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can call node_view on a revision loaded node (ie call node_load via node_load($nid, $vid) instead of node_load($nid) and get correctly themed results, then should be possible to make this, but yea, not currently implemented tmk.

(I think core should generally be fine, but may have some contrib that don't play along).

Comment: Could you use [Views node field](http://drupal.org/project/viewsnodefield) as a workaround? Created by one Mr hefox it says...